# Can BTDF deploy to a different SSO affiliate application than the name of the project?

Tags: biztalk, btdf

I'm trying to use BTDF where the SSO affiliate application is named different than the BizTalk application.  As far as I can tell, the projectname property is used for both the BizTalk application name and the SSO affiliate name.

Does BTDF allow you to update SSO settings to an affiliate application with a  different name than BizTalk application name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly, but it's trivial to implement. This works on MSBuild 4.0 or newer, placed in your .btdfproj:

```
<Target Name="DeploySSOCustom" AfterTargets="DeploySSO" Condition="'$(IncludeSSO)' == 'true'">
  <Exec Command="&quot;$(DeployTools)\SSOSettingsFileImport.exe&quot; &quot;$(MyOwnSSOAppName)&quot; /settingsFile:&quot;$(SettingsFilePath)&quot; /userGroupName:&quot;$(SsoAppUserGroup)&quot; /adminGroupName:&quot;$(SsoAppAdminGroup)&quot;"
    Condition="'$(SettingsFilePath)' != ''"/>
</Target>
```

Comment: Thanks!  This is exactly what I was looking for.  There is a slight edit on the first line (missing the double quote).  I couldn't edit it because it didn't meet the min characters.    I slightly modified this so it doesn't use the IncludeSSO property otherwise it adds SSO settings for both the projectname and the custom sso name.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the BTDF [documentation](http://www.tfabraham.com/BTDFDocs/V5_0/DeploymentFrameworkForBizTalkDocs.html?DeployConfigurationSettingsintoS.html), it looks like no, it does not currently support anything except a SSO Affiliate application apart from that of the project name.  Which is rather limiting in my opinion.

So you may want to think about extending the framework to cope with this.

The other options would be to write a script that gets called from BTDF or run manually (as you only need to run it once) that creates the SSO affiliate Applications using the ssomanage with the -creatapps & -createmappings options.